# iOS ARM: why no call to division routine from main()?

Tags: ios, c, assembly, arm

I am learning how the Mach-O symbolication process works and I wrote a simple C program to test some hypothesis. I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int division(int a, int b);

int m;

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("initializing i\n");
    i = 10;

    printf("initializing j\n");
    j=1;

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    m = division(i, j);

    printf("m = %d / %d = %d\n", i, j, m);

    return 0;
}

int division(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

It compiles using

> clang -Os  -Wimplicit -isysroot
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/
>   -arch armv7 -o helloworld helloworld.c

to the following ARM iOS assembly:

```
   EXPORT _main
__text:0000BEFC _main
__text:0000BEFC                 PUSH            {R4,R7,LR}
__text:0000BEFE                 MOVW            R0, #(:lower16:(aInitializingI - 0xBF0C)) ; "initializing i"
__text:0000BF02                 ADD             R7, SP, #4
__text:0000BF04                 MOVT.W          R0, #(:upper16:(aInitializingI - 0xBF0C)) ; "initializing i"
__text:0000BF08                 ADD             R0, PC  ; "initializing i"
__text:0000BF0A                 BLX             _puts
__text:0000BF0E                 MOV             R0, #(aInitializingJ - 0xBF1A) ; "initializing j"
__text:0000BF16                 ADD             R0, PC  ; "initializing j"
__text:0000BF18                 BLX             _puts
__text:0000BF1C                 MOVW            R0, #(:lower16:(aIDJD - 0xBF2C)) ; "i = %d, j = %d\n"
__text:0000BF20                 MOVS            R1, #0xA
__text:0000BF22                 MOVT.W          R0, #(:upper16:(aIDJD - 0xBF2C)) ; "i = %d, j = %d\n"
__text:0000BF26                 MOVS            R2, #1
__text:0000BF28                 ADD             R0, PC  ; "i = %d, j = %d\n"
__text:0000BF2A                 MOVS            R4, #0xA
__text:0000BF2C                 BLX             _printf
__text:0000BF30                 MOVW            R0, #(:lower16:(_m_ptr - 0xBF40))
__text:0000BF34                 MOVS            R2, #1
__text:0000BF36                 MOVT.W          R0, #(:upper16:(_m_ptr - 0xBF40))
__text:0000BF3A                 MOVS            R3, #0xA
__text:0000BF3C                 ADD             R0, PC ; _m_ptr
__text:0000BF3E                 LDR             R1, [R0] ; _m
__text:0000BF40                 MOV             R0, #(aMDDD - 0xBF4C) ; "m = %d / %d = %d\n"
__text:0000BF48                 ADD             R0, PC  ; "m = %d / %d = %d\n"
__text:0000BF4A                 STR             R4, [R1]
__text:0000BF4C                 MOVS            R1, #0xA
__text:0000BF4E                 BLX             _printf
__text:0000BF52                 MOVS            R0, #0
__text:0000BF54                 POP             {R4,R7,PC}
; End of function _main
__text:0000BF54
__text:0000BF54 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:0000BF56                 ALIGN 4
__text:0000BF58
__text:0000BF58 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
__text:0000BF58
__text:0000BF58
__text:0000BF58                 EXPORT _division
__text:0000BF58 _division
__text:0000BF58                 B.W             ___divsi3$shim
__text:0000BF58 ; End of function _division
__text:0000BF58
__text:0000BF5C
__text:0000BF5C ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
__text:0000BF5C
__text:0000BF5C
__text:0000BF5C ___divsi3$shim                          ; CODE XREF: _divisionj
__text:0000BF5C                 LDR.W           R12, loc_BF64
__text:0000BF60                 ADD             R12, PC ; ___divsi3
__text:0000BF62                 BX              R12
__text:0000BF64 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:0000BF64
__text:0000BF64 loc_BF64                                ; DATA XREF: ___divsi3$shimr
__text:0000BF64                 LSLS            R0, R2, #2
__text:0000BF66                 MOVS            R0, R0
__text:0000BF66 ; End of function ___divsi3$shim
__text:0000BF66
__text:0000BF66 ; __text        ends
__text:0000BF66
__stub_helper:0000BF68 ; ===========================================================================
__stub_helper:0000BF68

__stub_helper:0000BF68 ; Segment type: Pure code
__stub_helper:0000BF68                 AREA __stub_helper, CODE, READWRITE
__stub_helper:0000BF68                 ; ORG 0xBF68
__stub_helper:0000BF68                 CODE32
__stub_helper:0000BF68
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4 ; Attributes: thunk
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4 ___divsi3                               ; CODE XREF: ___divsi3$shim+6j
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4                                         ; DATA XREF: ___divsi3$shim+4o
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4                 LDR             PC, =__imp____divsi3
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4 ; End of function ___divsi3
__symbolstub1:0000BFF4
__symbolstub1:0000BFF8 ; [00000004 BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION _printf. PRESS KEYPAD CTRL-"+" TO EXPAND]
__symbolstub1:0000BFFC ; [00000004 BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION _puts. PRESS KEYPAD CTRL-"+" TO EXPAND]
__lazy_symbol:0000C000 ; ===========================================================================
__lazy_symbol:0000C000
__lazy_symbol:0000C000 ; Segment type: Pure data
__lazy_symbol:0000C000                 AREA __lazy_symbol, DATA
__lazy_symbol:0000C000                 ; ORG 0xC000
__lazy_symbol:0000C000 ___divsi3_ptr   DCD __imp____divsi3     ; DATA XREF: ___divsi3r
__lazy_symbol:0000C004 _printf_ptr     DCD __imp__printf       ; DATA XREF: _printfr
__lazy_symbol:0000C008 _puts_ptr       DCD __imp__puts         ; DATA XREF: _putsr
__lazy_symbol:0000C008 ; __lazy_symbol ends
__lazy_symbol:0000C008
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C ; ===========================================================================
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C ; Segment type: Pure data
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C                 AREA __nl_symbol_ptr, DATA
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C                 ; ORG 0xC00C
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C dyld_stub_binder_ptr DCD dyld_stub_binder
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C                                         ; DATA XREF: _stub_helpers+14o
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C00C                                         ; __stub_helper:off_BF88o
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C010 off_C010        DCD 0                   ; DATA XREF: _stub_helpers+8o
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C014 _m_ptr          DCD _m                  ; DATA XREF: _main+34o
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C014                                         ; _main+3Ao ...
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C014 ; __nl_symbol_ptr ends
__nl_symbol_ptr:0000C014
__common:0000C018 ; ===========================================================================
__common:0000C018
__common:0000C018 ; Segment type: Uninitialized
__common:0000C018                 AREA __common, DATA
__common:0000C018                 ; ORG 0xC018
__common:0000C018                 EXPORT _m
__common:0000C018 _m              % 1                     ; DATA XREF: _main+42o
__common:0000C018                                         ; __nl_symbol_ptr:_m_ptro
__common:0000C019                 % 1
__common:0000C01A                 % 1
__common:0000C01B                 % 1
__common:0000C01B ; __common      ends
__common:0000C01B
```

While I am aware that the optimisation in clang substitutes the division function into a call to divsi3 routine in libsystem.dylib, I do not see any call from the main routine to the ___divsi3 routine stub like BLX __division or something along the same lines. I am guessing instead of that, its now making use of the _m pointer. How does it work this way? Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is first inlining the 'division' function, which means that 'a / b' becomes 'i / j'. It then realizes that 'i / j' is a constant expression that always evaluates to '10 / 1', which evaluates at compile time to just '10' (or 0xA in hex).

This line loads '10' into R4 so it can later be written into 'm':

```
__text:0000BF2A                 MOVS            R4, #0xA
```

This line loads '10' into R3 so that 'm' is passed as the fourth printf parameter:

```
__text:0000BF3A                 MOVS            R3, #0xA
```

Sometimes compilers are really smart (like the inlining and compile-time constant expression evaluation) and sometimes they're really dumb (like redundantly loading '10' into both R4 and R3, instead of just storing R3 into 'm').

P.S. _m_ptr is just a memory location it uses to store the address of 'm'.

Comment: Interesting observation. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer! I'd say compilers are very smart when dealing with simple test codes, but unbelievably stupid when it actually matters.